# How can change orientaiton of camera as orientation get changed of device in iPhone/ios/ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have tabbar as Root controller. When i choose camera from view controller then it opens in Portrait mode, and then i change its orientation but it still in portrait mode and when pickerview dismissed and again change main view controller to landscape mpde then all 5 tabbar items are shown on left side. So it looks like all tabbar items icons are get disturbed. Can any one help to change camera orientation when phone orientaiton gets changed?

```
            if (self.pickerView) {
                self.pickerView = nil;
            }
            self.pickerView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            self.pickerView.delegate = self;
            self.pickerView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            self.pickerView.showsCameraControls = YES;
            self.pickerView.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
            self.pickerView.navigationBarHidden = YES;
            self.pickerView.toolbarHidden = FALSE;
            self.pickerView.allowsEditing=YES;
            [self presentViewController:self.pickerView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```